# Why can't we store the name of an overloaded function in an object of type function?

Tags: c++, dictionary, overloading

In C++ primer 5th edition p 578 it is said that

> We cannot store the name of an overloaded function in an object of type function

The provided code is :

```
int add (int i, int j) {return i+j;}
Sales_data add (const Sales_data&, const Sales_data&);
map <string, function <int(int, int)>>binops;
binops.insert ({"+", add}); // error : which add ?
```

What I do not understand is why the compiler cannot tell which add function to insert into the given map : the `add` which takes `Sales_data&` as argument does not match the function signature the map was created with and I would expect the compiler to be able to tell that the function to insert into the map is `int add (int i, intj) {return i+j;}`
Why does the compiler not know it ?

Comment: Good question, I'd love to know the answer to this as well. I'd guess it's because it can't infer the type of the function pointer int(add*)(int,int) from function <int(int, int)>.